# How to filter only volume data from kubectl describe <pod_name> command?

Tags: kubernetes, devops

I am doing some testing and has to filter only the volume information of respective k8s pod. I used kubectl describe po | grep volumes. But it is only displaying `volumes:`

Can someone suggest how can I filter the complete volume data from kubectl describe po command?

Complete Volume data  in kubectl describe command is below

```
Volumes:
  config-volume:
    Type:      XXX (a volume populated by XXX)
    Name:     Volum-1
    Optional:  false
  Volum-1:
    Type: YYY (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  default-token-zzz:
    Type:        www (a volume populated by a www)
    SecretName:  default-token-zzz
    Optional:    false
```

Comment: What makes you think that this isn't the complete list of volumes?

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl describe` output is "human readable", which is not that easy to parse, but also it does not guarantee you a consistent format over different releases. If you want to programmatically get some information from kubectl, you should use `kubectl get` with either `-o jsonpath` or `-o go-template`

For example, to get all volumes you can use something like

```
kubectl get pod your_pod -o jsonpath='{.spec.volumes}'
```

To get volume names use

```
kubectl get pod your_pod -o jsonpath='{.spec.volumes[*].name}'
```

See https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/ for reference